# Conflicting package versions when installing @solana packages

Tags: spl-token, react

I am building a React-based app that uses many dependencies and I am running into a problem with [@metaplex-foundation/js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@metaplex-foundation/js) and [@solana/spl-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/spl-token) in particular.

I want to use the newest versions of both packages, but the `@metaplex-foundation/js` package has a transient dependency of an older version of the `@solana/spl-token package`.

`yarn list @solana/spl-token` output:

```
yarn list v1.22.19
warning Filtering by arguments is deprecated. Please use the pattern option instead.
├─ @metaplex-foundation/js@0.17.2
│  └─ @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata@2.3.3
│     └─ @solana/spl-token@0.2.0
├─ @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata@2.3.0
│  └─ @solana/spl-token@0.2.0
└─ @solana/spl-token@0.3.5
```

The problem is that I am trying to use features only available in the 0.3.5 version of spl-token, but it seems to me that I am locked into using 0.2.0. Is there a way for me to work around this?

[image: The error within VS Code]

Comment: It looks like the solution to my problem is using npm/yarn aliases: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add#toc-yarn-add-alias


`yarn add @solana/spl-token-next@npm:@solana/spl-token`
The current problem is that VS Code still doesn't resolve the aliased version as a different package, it still sees it as the 0.2.0 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to add my comment as the answer to this:

It looks like the solution to my problem is using [npm/yarn aliases](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add#toc-yarn-add-alias) with a command such as `yarn add @solana/spl-token-next@npm:@solana/spl-token`.

This still has some awkward problems with VS Code in some cases not resolving the aliased version as a different package, but it does work.